# Is this a simply connected set and how can we prove?

Tags: calculus, connectedness

I get the intuitive idea of a simply connected set ( any closed curve could be shrinked to a point). Can you please state the precise definition of a simply connected set and how can we use it to prove that this set is simply connected ?

As I feel this set goes against the intuitive idea of a simply connected set?

Set is    $\mathbb{R^2}$ \ {$(0,0)$} .

Comment: You need to tell us what definition of simply connected *you* have been given. Why do you think the set is simply connected? And what tools do you have? Do you know about line integrals, for example? You have to provide a *lot* more in your question.

Comment: Do you know about fundamental groups?

Comment: You are basically asking to explain to you the homotopy theory. I think if you google the notion of fundamental group your question would be answered. Or you can read it in Hatcher’s book for example.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I will refer on them. But could you please verify whether the the set that I stated is a simply connected one or not?

Comment: @TedShifrin So the problem that I'm trying to solve is that this system has no closed orbit using the Bendixons' criteria. X' = Y + (X*(Y^2)) , Y' = - Y + (Y*(X^2)) . My problem is at the origin divF (system is F) becomes zero. and further the R^2\ (0,0) is not simply connected. So can we use Bendixons' criteria ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in (multivariable) calculus, the definition usually goes like this:

**Defintion:**  A plane region $D$ is simply connected if it is connected and every simple closed curve in $D$ surrounds only points in $D$.

In your case, the unit circle traces out a simple closed curve in $D=\mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0)\}$.  However, that curve surrounds the origin, which is not a point in $D$.  Hence $D$ is not simply connected (though it is connected).

Comment: So the problem that I'm trying to solve is that this system has no closed orbit using the Bendixons' criteria. X' = Y + (X*(Y^2)) , Y' = - Y + (Y*(X^2)) . My problem is at the origin divF (system is F) becomes zero. and further the R^2\ (0,0) is not simply connected. So can we use Bendixons' criteria ?

Comment: That's a very different and much more focused question.  Seems like you should be asking that.

Comment: Okay. I posted it as a question. Thank you. I'm new to the site.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can talk about a simply connected *topological space*, not about a simply connected *set*.

The definition is that a space $X$ is simply connected if

1. it is connected
2. for every continuous map $f:\Bbb S^1\to X$ there is a map $g:\Bbb D^2\to X$ such that $f=g|_{\partial \Bbb D^2}$.

The second condition can be roughly worded as "every closed curve can be shrunk to a point", like you said. The continuous image of a disk is what tells you how to shrink its boundary to its center.

Comment: Is the set that I stated a simply connected set? . Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @Mod_x No it's not. The standard unit circle can't be shrunk to a point. There are dozens of proofs. You need to say more about what you know and what you've tried.

Comment: It's not the standard unit circle, R^2 \ (0,0)

Comment: So the problem that I'm trying to solve is that this system has no closed orbit using the Bendixons' criteria. X' = Y + (X*(Y^2)) , Y' = - Y + (Y*(X^2)) . My problem is at the origin divF (system is F) becomes zero. and further the R^2\ (0,0) is not simply connected. So can we use Bendixons' criteria ?

Comment: @Mod_x This is essential and should go in the body of the question.

Comment: Thank you. I posted it as a new question. I'm new to the site.